# Chimney Equation derivation mysterious identity

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I have been studying the basic chimney equation derived by the [engineering toolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/chimney-sizing-d_175.html)

Try as I might, I cannot figure out how they arrived at the identity $$\rho_0 \cdot T_0=\rho_i \cdot T_i$$ They hint vaguely that this follows from the ideal gas law. Considering that this is the crux of the entire derivation, I find it a little odd they didn't expand on this more.

Comment: hint:$pV=m\tfrac{R}{M}T$, $p=const$, what is $m/V$?

Comment: why can you assume that pressure $p$ is constant? I thought the whole system operated on the assumption that the pressure in the chimney was less than the pressure outside the chimney

Comment: the chimney is an "open air" system, at least mine is, as far as I know.

Comment: O.K. I think I understand. Since the chimney is open to the environment, pressure is allowed to equalize between the chimney and the ambient environment.

Comment: Is the definition of an "open air" system that pressure is constant?

Comment: The *environment* has pressure 1bar that is aside from some occasional weather events varying it by a few percent, and it acts as a work reservoir. The "thermodynamic system" consisting of the chimney, furnace, etc, has different pressures but by the time the hot gas leaves the chimney and enters and mixes in the atmosphere it is ~1bar.

Comment: So the model assumes that as air leaves the chimney it's pressure drops to whatever the ambient pressure is, but it's temperature remains constant?